# Residues on Series expansion with orders

Tags: complex-analysis

Given
$$\begin{align} \dots&+\frac1{z^2}+\frac1{z}+1+z+z^2+\dots\tag{1}\\ 
\frac1{z^2}&+\frac1{z}+1+z+z^2+\dots\tag{2}\\
\dots&+\frac1{z^4}+\frac1{z^2}+1+z^2+z^4+\dots,\tag{3}
\end{align}$$

there are terms of order $>1$ for the series $(1)$ and $(2)$. Shall I take the orders into consideration or take the coefficient at $1/z$ as the residue instead?

And how can I get the residue for third series?

Comment: The residue of a function with a Laurent series representation at a point is always simply the coefficient of the $1/z$ term. Having no $1/z$ term is the same as having a coefficient of zero for that term.

Comment: Thank you very much!!